# Lengthening a string using characters from another

Tags: bash

I have a string `dk` of length `N`, and a numeric value `NDK`.

If `N` is less than `NDK` I want to append the difference from the start of another string called `SYMBOL`.

```
if (( n < ndk )); then
  df=$(( ndk - n ))
fi
```

Thus if the difference `df` is `2`, I want to append the first two characters from the string `SYMBOL` to the string `DK`.

```
symbol="!@#$%^&"

df=2
dk="FIRST"
```

With the resulting value of `dk` being

```
"FIRST!@"
```

How can I append the additional `df` characters from the beginning of string `SYMBOL` ?

Comment: What would you want happen if `$df` is larger than `${#symbol}` (the length of the `$symbol` string)?

Comment: I have ensured that condition is never true.  Thus `DF` is always less than the length of `SYMBOL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
df=3
dk=hello
symbol=123456

dk+=${symbol:0:df}
```

This appends the `$df` first characters from `$symbol` to the end of the string in `$dk`.

The value in `$dk` at the end of the above code would be `hello123`.

The `+=` operator appends the value to the right of the operator to the end of the value of the variable to the left of the operator.

The `${variable:offset:length}` expansion in `bash` returns the `length` long substring starting at `offset` (a zero-based index) from the variable `variable`.  Both `offset` and `length` are evaluated in an arithmetic context.

Comment: Can the length of a string be included in arithmetic operation `df=$(( ${#str} - n ))`.  Because usually one does not use `$` in front of the variable in the arithmetic construct `((...))`.

Comment: @Randy, yes (try it), and that's a case where you have to use the expansion form with the `$`. You could also do the arithmetic as part of the substring expansion, like  `${symbol:0: ${#str} - n }`. Except of course that if the count goes negative, the meaning changes, with `s=12345678`,  `${s:0: -3}` gives `12345`, i.e. ending at three chars before the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to `r`ight-pad `$dk` to the length of `$ndk` using characters from `$symbols`, in `zsh`:

```
$ dk=FIRST ndk=7 symbol='!@#$%^&'
$ printf '%s\n' ${(pr[ndk][$symbol])dk}
FIRST!@
$ ndk=20
$ printf '%s\n' ${(pr[ndk][$symbol])dk}
FIRST!@#$%^&!@#$%^&!
```

That uses the `r[length][string]` right-padding *parameter expansion flag*. The `p` flags changes how the `$symbol` is interpreted. Without `p`, the padding string would be `$symbol` literally.

Beware that if `$dk` is longer than `$ndk` characters, it will truncate it.

To pad to a *width* of `$ndk` *columns* instead of to a *length* of `$ndk` *characters*, that is to take into account the display width of each character, add the `m` parameter expansion flag.

To pad to a number of *byte* instead of *characters* (which would make a difference if there were multibyte characters in either `$dk` or `$symbols`), you'd disable the `multibyte` option of set the locale to `C` (and not use the `m` flag).

See `info zsh flags` for details.